# I want to resolve errors that occurred on Asterisk sip server

Tags: asterisk, sip

Nice to meet you

I am building a SIP server using Asterisk.
The environmental composition is as follows.

=================================================
 -- SIP Server--
Asterisk 15.6.1 built by root @ taka-machine-9010 on a x86_64 running Linux on 2018-11-09 06:20:43 UTC
Linux version 4.15.0-38-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-023) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018

 -- SIP Client --
Phone version: Zoiper5 5.2.19 for Windows 64bit
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.345]
=================================================

In this environment, attempting to connect to the server from the client will result in "SIP UDP Not found".
Please tell me the cause and solution.

For TCP communication at error occurrence, Wireshark is capturing. Capture content and Asterisk settings are in the following ZIP file.

https://ufile.io/73jev

; sip.conf
[general]
context=default
transport=udp
port=5060
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
language=ja
localnet=192.168.104.0/255.255.255.0
domain=192.168.104.113

[201]
type=friend
username=201
secret=p@w0ssRd
host=dynamic
canreinvite=no

[202]
type=friend
username=202
secret=p@w0ssRd
host=dynamic
canreinvite=no

[203]
type=friend
username=203
secret=p@w0ssRd
host=dynamic
canreinvite=no


; extensions.conf
[default]
;
; By default we include the demo.  In a production system, you
; probably don't want to have the demo there.
;
;include => demo
exten => 201,1,Dial(SIP/201,30,r)
exten => 201,2,Hangup()

exten => 202,1,Dial(SIP/202,30,r)
exten => 202,2,Hangup()

exten => 203,1,Answer()
exten => 203,2,Playback(hello-world)
exten => 203,3,Hangup()

Answer (score -1):

First, sorry, I cannot download the pcap you have linked via ufile.io.

The error appears to be from the Zoiper side when it does not get a response from the server. A couple of suggestions:

1) Use command "asterisk -rvvvvvv" and try to register your Zoiper client. You should see the registration attempt in the CLI output. If not, check the IP route between the client and asterisk.

2) Since you are using localnet= parameter in sip.conf, maybe your server is behind a NAT. If this is the case, I can suggest that you also enable externip= parameter in sip.conf [general]

3) If your Zoiper client is behind NAT, add nat=force_rport,comedia to each of your 20x peers.

4) Also, make sure that your Zoiper client is communicating on 5060 UDP and did not default to IAX 4569

Good luck!